# Browser API | Close window programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, browser, webapi

Is there an API that can be used to close a tab programmatically? I know there is the method `window.close()`, but it can be used only for the windows that were opened by a script using the `window.open()` method.

What I am trying to do is create a menu button for the users that once clicked will close the current tab or all other tabs if the current tab has been duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an API that can be used to close a tab programmatically?

### NO it is impossible,

*For security reasons*, a window can only be closed in `JavaScript` if it was opened by `JavaScript`.

You must edit your code and use `windows.open()`, to use `windows.close()` method.

Comment: Please inform me if it helps, I knew it, but I did research to to make sure of this

Comment: Thank you! That's how I found out too, but I wanted to ask if anyone knows of another solution as it's a good use case. Maybe not to close directly for security reasons, but try to close programmatically, and the user will be notified through a pop-up at the browser level that the window is trying to close.

Comment: Tank you too!, But how will you close?, because there are no other options except the window.close() method, for security reasons in JS they didn’t add the option to close the window, so it’s impossible no matter how much we tried

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean when you say-  " but try to close programmatically, and the user will be notified through a pop-up at the browser level that the window is trying to close", there is not variant to close, and if you will through some notification about closing the window it will be like **fake** ))

Comment: When` window.close` is called, the browser should display a popup saying that the window wants to close and if the user confirms this.

Comment: Yeh that's right, what then?